# How can I average several inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code a calculator with several options, just for the leraning experience, and one of these options is 'average', I want the user to be able to input as many values as he wants to, but it's not working yet, what should I change?

This is my code for the average so far:

```
elif ui1 == subop1_2:
            1 = [input("Input your values, separate with a comma").split(',')]
            result = sum(1) / float(len(1))
            print("The average is {}".format(result))
            time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: You can't name a variable `1`.

Comment: You `can't assign to a literal` meaning that variable name can't be number `1`. Change it into something like `a`.

Comment: You also need to convert the items in your list from a string to an int or float.

Comment: Also, I think the [..] is too much, the split already outputs a list.

Comment: You should probably guard against division by zero if the user decides to enter no items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing you wrote was perfectly fine except a few mistakes...

1) Change all 1s to a valid variable name. Lets say, a.
2) Remove the square brackets around the input() function
3) Add a this line before the line where you assign the variable, result.

```
a = [int(x) for x in a]
```

Here is the code,

```
a = input("Input your values, separate with a comma").split(',')
a = [int(x) for x in a]
result = sum(a) / float(len(a))
print("The average is {}".format(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there were a lot of things pointed out, here goes an answer.

```
num_list = input("Input your values, separate with a comma: ").split(',')
num_list = [float(elem) for elem in num_list]
result = sum(num_list) / float(len(num_list))
```

This will fail if the user enters an empty string or characters...

Comment: I don't like the fact you reuse num_list. Doesn't make it clear.

Comment: What would you change?

Comment: I would use map and not reuse the variables. Rest is fine.

Answer (score 0):

first of all u cannot name a variable:1 change that to "a" or something and it should work out

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
inp = input("Input your values, separate with a comma")
values = list(map(float,inp.split(',')))
avg = sum(values)/len(values)
print("The average is {}".format(avg))
```